# In Ruby, can I hand off variables from within a method without making new global variables?

Tags: ruby, global-variables, local-variables

I'm doing a game creation exercise from Learn Ruby the Hard Way. It's themed after Destiny since that's what I've got on the brain at the moment.

I wanted to have the player pick a character class, and then have that choice hand off some numbers as stats to be checked later in play. Below is the version that actually worked, but it involves creating a several global variables, which I keep reading is not a "best practice" in Ruby.

My question is, is there a way to do what I've got the code below doing without creating all of these global variables, or am I doing what needs to be done?

```
$might = 1
$agility = 1
$intellect = 1

def start
  puts "Make all decisions by pressing the corresponding number."
  puts "Choose your class:"
  puts "1. Titan"
  puts "2. Hunter"
  puts "3. Warlock"

  print "> "
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp


  if choice == "1"
    $might = 3
    puts "You've chosen Titan!"
  elsif choice == "2"
    $agility = 3
    puts "You've chosen Hunter!"
  elsif choice == "3"
    $intellect = 3
    puts "You've chosen Warlock!"
  else
    puts "Try again."
    start
  end
end

puts start

puts "Might: #{$might}"
puts "Agility: #{$agility}"
puts "Intellect: #{$intellect}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class and use instance variables:

```
class Game
  def initialize
    @might = 1
    @agility = 1
    @intellect = 1
  end
  attr_reader :might
  attr_reader :agility
  attr_reader :intellect
  def start
    puts "Make all decisions by pressing the corresponding number."
    puts "Choose your class:"
    puts "1. Titan"
    puts "2. Hunter"
    puts "3. Warlock"

    print "> "
    choice = $stdin.gets.chomp


    case choice 
      when "1"
        @might = 3
        puts "You've chosen Titan!"
      when "2"
        @agility = 3
        puts "You've chosen Hunter!"
      when "3"
        @intellect = 3
        puts "You've chosen Warlock!"
      else
        puts "Try again."
        start
    end
  end
end
game = Game.new
game.start

puts "Might: #{game.might}"
puts "Agility: #{game.agility}"
puts "Intellect: #{game.intellect}"
```

Remark:

- I replaced your if-sequence with a case-statement
- `attr_reader` defined the attribute accessor for the instance variables.

Comment: You can use attr_reader in one line like attr_reader :might, :agility, :intelect

Comment: @LukasBaliak I prefer the version with single definitions. If I add a comment line, then I get different documentations for the attributes.

Comment: Yes, you right. I just write another way to do it :)

Comment: All of the answers were great, but I really appreciated the simplicity of this answer combined with the clear remarks for documented changes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. I prepare it for updates.

```
class Character
  attr_accessor :might, :agility, :intelect, :type
  def initialize(type, might = 1, agility = 1, intelect = 1)
    @type = type
    @might, @agility, @intelect = might, agility, intelect
  end

  def print_attributes
    puts "Type: #{@type}"
    puts "Might: #{@might}"
    puts "Agility: #{@agility}"
    puts "Intelect: #{@intelect}"
  end
end

class Player
  attr_reader :character
  def initialize(character)
    @character = character
  end
end

class Game
  CHARACTER_CLASSES = [
    {:type => "Titan", :might => 3, :agility => 1, :intelect => 1},
    {:type => "Hunter", :might => 1, :agility => 3, :intelect => 1},
    {:type => "Warlock", :might => 1, :agility => 1, :intelect => 3}
  ]

  attr_reader :player
  def initialize
    @player = nil
  end

  def start
    puts "Make all decisions by pressing the corresponding number."
    repeat = true
    while repeat
      puts "Choose your class:"
      CHARACTER_CLASSES.each_with_index do |char_config, i|
        puts "#{i+1}. #{char_config[:type]}"
      end

      choice = gets.chomp
      choice_i = choice.to_i
      unless choice_i == 0
        if char_data = CHARACTER_CLASSES[choice_i - 1]
          @player = Player.new( Character.new(char_data[:type], char_data[:might], char_data[:agility], char_data[:intelect]) )
          repeat = false
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

game = Game.new
game.start
game.player.character.print_attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be returning whatever you want from a method:

```
def start
  puts "Make all decisions by pressing the corresponding number."
  puts "Choose your class:"
  puts "1. Titan"
  puts "2. Hunter"
  puts "3. Warlock"

  print "> "
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  case choice
  when '1'
    puts "You've chosen Titan!"
    {agility: 1, might: 3, intellect: 1}
  when '2'
    puts "You've chosen Hunter!"
    {agility: 3, might: 1, intellect: 1}
  when '3'
    puts "You've chosen Warlock!"
    {agility: 1, might: 1, intellect: 3}
  else
    puts "Try again."
    start
  end
end

hero = start

puts "Might: #{hero[:might]}"
puts "Agility: #{hero[:agility]}"
puts "Intellect: #{hero[:intellect]}"
```